# Undefined reference to EVP_idea_ecb on Debian

Tags: gcc, openssl, debian, evp-cipher

I have the following code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <openssl/evp.h>
int main (int argc, char *argv[]) {
    EVP_CIPHER *cipher;
    EVP_idea_ecb();
}
```

I know, this is not much, but it should compile without complaints, but I get

```
gcc Testfile.c -lssl -lcrypto
Testfile.c:(.text+0xec): undefined reference to `EVP_idea_ecb'

gcc Testfile.c -lss
/usr/bin/ld: /tmp/ccgbkhFA.o: undefined reference to symbol 'EVP_CIPHER_iv_length@@OPENSSL_1.0.0'
//usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libcrypto.so.1.0.0: error adding symbols: DSO missing from command linel
```

`libssl-dev` are installed. Any ideas what is going wrong here?

My distro: Debian Jessie on x64.

Comment: You also need to call `OpenSSL_add_ssl_algorithms` and `SSL_load_error_strings`. See [Library Initialization](http://wiki.openssl.org/index.php/Library_Initialization) on the OpenSSL wiki. `OpenSSL_add_ssl_algorithms` and `SSL_library_init` are synonymous (you can use either one, but one should be used).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What is going on line by line:

```
gcc Testfile.c -lssl -lcrypto
Testfile.c:(.text+0xec): undefined reference to `EVP_idea_ecb'
```

OpenSSL library of Debian Jessie x64 doesn't contain  EVP_idea_ecb.

```
gcc Testfile.c -lss
/usr/bin/ld: /tmp/ccgbkhFA.o: undefined reference to symbol 'EVP_CIPHER_iv_length@@OPENSSL_1.0.0'
//usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libcrypto.so.1.0.0: error adding symbols: DSO missing from command linel
```

libss.so.2.0  from libss2 command line interface library package doesn't help either.

Comment: *"OpenSSL library of Debian Jessie x64 doesn't contain EVP_idea_ecb"* - you should use something like `nm -D /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libcrypto.so | grep -i EVP_idea_ecb` to confirm (or deny) the symbol. Its not present in Wheezy either.

Comment: Thanks for your comment. Yes, EVP_idea is not avaible in libcrypto.so so that's why gcc is returning this error. But in evp.h there is a symbol, that's I thought, that this function should be availble and im calling gcc with the wrong parameters. I installed Fedora in Virtualbox. Now I can do what I want.