# Linker error: undefined reference to `EVP_idea_cbc'

Tags: c++, openssl, linker-errors, libcurl

I was compiling openssl 1.0.1l on Ubuntu 14.10, I used the following instructions to build the library.

```
./config 
make -j4
```

But when I use it with libCURL, it gives me the following linker error:

```
libssl.a(ssl_algs.o): In function `SSL_library_init':
ssl_algs.c:(.text+0x1f): undefined reference to `EVP_idea_cbc'
```

Really wired. This version of openssl is working properly on other platform.

Any suggestions would be appreciated.

Thanks.

Comment: It seems you just [don't link to libcrypto](http://stackoverflow.com/a/23025421/4074081)

Comment: @frymode  yes, I'm not linking the prebuilt version of crypto, it links to the system crypto.  I forget to delete the CMake cache.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Undefined reference to EVP\_idea\_ecb](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27903198/undefined-reference-to-evp-idea-ecb-on-debian)

Answer (score 0):

I'm using CMake to compile my project. But I don't delete the cache and it still link to the system crypto library, not the prebuilt version of my own.

I use `make VERBOSE=1` to identify this mistake.